# how to print '\n' and not '\\n'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a application where I am using some auto generate regular expressions which are multi line is the reg Ex string contains `\n`.

Now every time i execute a generate command i would like to print the command to console also for documentation ect.

```
INFO: Command execute: (regular expression)
```

however if i just print my Reg Ex string containing the `\n` I also get newline in the printout which is not desirable.

```
INFO: Command execute: (regular expre
ssion)
```

I can get it to print the newline `\n` by adding an escape char making it `\\n` and it is also how it looks on the print out.

```
INFO: Command execute: (regular expre\\nssion)
```

This is not desirable either. What I am looking for is to be able to print it like following.

```
INFO: Command execute: (regular expre\nssion)
```

Is this possible ?

regards

Comment: How exactly are you "printing" this? `print('regular expre\\nssion')` prints `'regular expre\nssion'` on my computer

Comment: @Markus Well its a slight more complicated than that, first i use `re.escape(my_str)` to make a fully valid regular expression compatible string. The i compile it and print it using `print(compiledStr.pattern) `. However I found that the pattern string was `\\\n` and that was why it wasnt not working. i replace the `\\\n` with `\\n` and i get your result.

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in function `repr()` to get the string that would reproduce that object when evaluated:

```
>>> text = 'INFO: Command execute: (regular expre\nssion)'
>>> print(text)
INFO: Command execute: (regular expre
ssion)
>>> print(repr(text))
'INFO: Command execute: (regular expre\nssion)'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. String prefix `r` makes it ignore all escapes.

```
a = r"Hello\nworld"
print a # Hello\nworld
```

If you still need new lines while using `r`, you can use triple quote sintax

```
b = r"""Big \n long
\n
string"""
print b
# Big \n long
# \n
# string
```